# Table of contents: numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I used this code in order to create the table of content but I don't want the pages of the table of contents to be counted.
I mean the number 2 at the end of page one and the number 3 at the top of page 2 with the word INDICE. How can I eliminate them? Thank you in advance!

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
```

Answer (score 1):

The macro `\thispagestyle` only affects the single page that follows it. Since your table of contents has two pages, the second page thus goes back to the previous setting. Use `\pagestyle` before and after your table of contents such that it will be applied to all pages of the table of contents.

This should work:

```
\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain} % replace plain with the pagestyle you want
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work properly - I mean in the second page there is no number at the top of the page but in the first one there is still the number two at the bottom

Comment: Then please show a minimal but complete compilable code ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)) so that we can better understand what is happening there. Might be that you need to put the first `\pagestyle` above some other macros, but without proper code I can only guess.